# Can array and nullable types be used before they are declared?

Tags: c#, arrays, nullable

I quote the following paragraphs from the book: 
**The C# Programming Language
Fourth Edition**

> C# supports single- and
>   multi-dimensional arrays of any type.
>   Unlike the types listed above, array
>   types do not have to be declared
>   before they can be used. Instead,
>   array types are constructed by
>   following a type name with square
>   brackets. For example, int[] is a
>   single-dimensional array of int,
>   int[,] is a two-dimensional array of
>   int, and int[][] is a
>   single-dimensional array of
>   single-dimensional arrays of int.

and

> Nullable types also do not have to be
>   declared before they can be used. For
>   each non-n ullable value type T there
>   is a corresponding nullable type T?,
>   which can hold an additional value
>   null. For instance, int? is a type
>   that can hold any 32 bit integer or
>   the value null.

How to use array and nullable types without declaring them in advance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**

What those quotations are trying to say is that you don't have to "create" (or **declare**) array and nullable value types, in the same way you declare custom classes, in order to use them. They are already available as C# language features.

**Long answer**

If you want to declare an array of `int`s, simply do this:

```
int[] intArray = new int[5];
```

If you made a custom class, for example `Foo`, and you want to declare an array of `Foo` objects, the first quotation is saying that you don't have to write code to tell the compiler about an array type that can hold `Foo` objects; just do this and the compiler will figure out the rest:

```
Foo[] fooArray = new Foo[5];
```

Similarly, to create items of nullable value types simply append `?` to the type:

```
int? nullableInt = null;
```

Additionally, the above is just syntactic sugar for the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) struct:

```
Nullable<int> nullableInt = null;
```

Note that this only applies to value types (including structs), as all reference types (objects, delegates, etc) are nullable by default.